# Object Oriented adding items to an a arrayList

Tags: java, list, oop, arraylist

I'm new to object orientated languages and just have a few questions about adding items to an `ArrayList`. I've come up with a solution however I'm confused as I've seen another method used which I don't understand. Could someone please explain to me how the second method works?

**I have two classes one for an item in a shop:**

```
public class Item {
    String name;
    double weight;
    double price;
    
    public Item(String itemName,double itemWeight, double itemPrice){
        this.name = itemName;
        this.weight = itemWeight;
        this.price = itemPrice;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return(name + " has a weight of " + weight + " and a price of " + price);
    }    
}
```

**And another of an arraylist of items in the shop:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ItemList{
    String itemName;
    ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
     
    public ItemList(String name) {
        itemName = name;
    }
    public void addItem(Item item1){
        itemList.add(item1);
    }
    public void printItems(){
        for(int i=0; i < itemList.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(itemList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

**I then have a main method that adds items to the list then prints them:**

```
public class ShopMain {
    public static void main (String[] args){
         ItemList myList = new ItemList("Fruit");
         Item apple = new Item("Apple", 100, 60);
         myList.addItem(apple);
         Item banana = new Item("Banana", 118, 50);
         myList.addItem(banana);
         
         myList.printItems();
    }
}
```

**However the second method I've seen people use doesn't work for me and is formatted like this:**

```
public class HopefulShopMain{
    public static void main (String[] args){
         ItemList myList = new ItemList("Fruit");
         
         myList.addItem("Apple", 100, 60);
         myList.addItem("Banana", 118, 50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a new function to the `ItemList` class: `public void addItem(String itemName,double itemWeight, double itemPrice) { itemList.add(new Item (itemName, itemWeight, itemPrice));}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `addItem` method takes an `item`, so the second snippet won't work, at least not with the implementation of `ItemList` being what it is. You could of course add it to your class:

```java
public void addItem(String name, double weight, double price) {
    itemList.add(new Item(name, weight, price));
}
```

There is an argument to be made here that implementing `ItemList` like that hides the `Item` class from whoever uses `ItemList` - this may or may not be appropriate, depending on how you intend these two class to be used.